# Is there a way to send email from Spotfire on a button click?

Tags: javascript, r, email, ironpython, spotfire

i am looking for an option to send email form a button click in spotfire text area using iron python

(or)

can we  implement same with the help of iron python and Automation Services.

(or)

Is there a way to get it done using R programming

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook")
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal


mail= Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
mail.Recipients.Add("abc@xyz.com")
mail.Subject = "subject here"
mail.Body = "Body here"
mail.Send();
```

the above code is to send email , it is working fine within spotfire Client but not in web player.please help me out

Comment: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire-automation-services/7.7.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_autsvcs_7.7.0_user_manual/GUID-4BAA0BE3-249C-4CD8-B791-C5021788CCF4.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @scsimon ,i am not completely looking to depend completely on Automation services . is there a way to  send an email when user clicks on a link/button in text area. 
or even is there a way to trigger automation services when clicking on a link or button

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mailR package to trigger emails.This is what worked for me-

```
sender <- "sender@gmail.com" 
recipient<- "receiver1@gmail.com" 
email <- send.mail(from = sender,to = recipients,subject="R-email",body = 
"Body of the email",smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
user.name="myuser@gmail.com",passwd="password",port=587,ssl=TRUE),authenticate 
= TRUE,send = FALSE)
email$send()
```